# Facing issue in node registration

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nodes

While trying to add a node in gke cluster facing error

Error message is

All clusters resources are brought up:but only 0 nodes out of 10  have registered

How to fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-node-registration#error-message-for-node-registration) this error message demonstrates that the nodes did not successfully register with the cluster.

`The following sections describe some of the potential causes of this error:`

- **Instance creation might fail for one of the following reasons**:  Insufficient quota, Resource availability, Insufficient IP address
  space.
- **Service account issues** : If you delete the service account, disable it, or do not give it the correct permissions, node
  registration might fail.
- **Network connection to Google APIs and services** : The VM instance downloads packages to prepare to run as a GKE node.If an instance
  cannot connect to these services, it cannot download the Kubernetes
  distribution and complete the node registration process.
- **Network connection with control plane** : Connectivity between the control plane and the nodes is critical for node registration and
  regular function.

***Using the below log filter you need to Find an instance that failed node registration :***

> ```
> resource.type="gce_instance"
> logName="projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
> protoPayload.requestMetadata.callerSuppliedUserAgent="GCE Managed Instance Group for GKE"
> protoPayload.response.status="RUNNING"
>
>
> Replace PROJECT_ID with the project ID for your cluster.
> ```

Follow this [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-node-registration#node-registration-checker) doc for step by step process to Find an instance that failed node registration and follow this [Troubleshoot an instance with the Node Registration Checker](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-node-registration#use-nrc)  to check the reason. Based on the reason you get follow below docs to resolve this issue.

> If LOGGING, GCR, or GCS are listed as not reachable, check the
> [Service account permissions for node
> registration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-node-registration#service-account-permissions)
> and [Network connection to Google APIs and services for node
> registration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-node-registration#network-connection-to-apis).
>
> If Master is listed as not reachable, check the prerequisites for
> [Network connection with control plane for node
> registration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-node-registration#network-connection-to-control-plane).
>
> After you resolve all issues preventing successful node registration,
> refer to [Complete node registration after fixing the root
> cause](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-node-registration#next-steps).
>
> If the preceding steps don't tell you why node registration failed,
> refer to [Gather information for further
> investigation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-node-registration#get-info-for-investigation).

Comment: I too found  above document